# In retrospect, best open source stack/tools to build facebook

Tags: google-app-engine, web-applications

I have been doing high performance scientific computing in c++ most of my life. I am trying to learn to developing AJAXy web applications. As an exercise, I would like to build something that has a subset of functionality of facebook (profiles, posts with comment threads, friend lists) + the ability to search any post/comment.

I have no experience developing these kind of apps, except minor amount of toying with Google Appengine with GWT+Java and little bit of python. What tools/stack would you suggest using for it? I understand that this a very vague question, but I'd like to get a few opinions and your thought process about how would you go about using it.

How does the choice change, if you want a fast prototype as fast as possible, vs if you are trying to build something that can scale and last a few cycles of feature requests.

To be more specific, I'm lost in questions like, should I consider Drupal, should I consider Lucene for search, Would GWT get me what I want in the UI or would python+django be faster to develop. Probably I should not over think and pick something. But some perspective from others would be nice.

Comment: This question is probably better suited to the [programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) stackexchange

Answer (score 3):

If you have started out with Python, that might be the easiest to get going with, especially since you have some experience with Google's App Engine already.  However, if you have spent most of your time working with C++ ... did you know that C++ has at least two different full-stack web frameworks?

- [CppCMS](http://cppcms.sourceforge.net/wikipp/en/page/main)
- [Wt (WebToolkit)](http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt)

Remember, it's what you develop fastest in that makes the difference in the long run.  What will slow you down most of all is dealing with what you dislike.  So, if long compile times kill you, then try Python, Ruby, PHP, or some other dynamic language.  If having code that is less than perfectly optimized (and slower that it could be) is what bothers you most, use C++, C#, or Java instead.

Answer (score 1):

One disadvantage with google app engine is that there is no CMS like drupal or Joomla for google app engine so you're going to have to write your own if you want some of that functionality. The advantages of google app engine however outweigh the disadvantage since you have easier development, easier deployment, won't have to fiddle with phpmyadmin or other ugly sql interfaces, with app engine you also leverage google's huge infrastructure and since it's cloud computing you only pay for what you use. If you want something you as a developer will be most happy about - then I recommend you choose Google App Engine.